# Angular 7 Assets folder for images is slowing down website loading

Tags: image, lazy-loading, angular7, assets

I am currently trying to optimize my one page angular application. 
Currently using angular cli @7.3.8. On my most recent ng build it takes 109131ms. I believe the cause of the slow build process is due to my assets folder being 18.2mb. 
Should I outsource my images to flickr or imgur and directly link to them on those sites or would it be better to downsize those images effecting the quality of them to create a faster load time?

I also have been looking into lazyloading. Would that be the better option?

Comment: ng build time is the time to **build** your application. It has nothing to do with load time. I doubt the time has anything to do with the size of your assets folder: copying 18.2MB of files should be almost instantaneous. lazy loading allows reducing the time to load the main bundle. It won't reduce your build time. Why don't you just remove the assets folder and measure the time it takes: you would know, instead of making assumptions.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Appreciate the troubleshoot should've thought of that, I'll test that out. Is there a troubleshoot method for figuring out load time issues? Every time I tab out of my website and come back it takes like 3 seconds to load back.

Comment: First: if you're measuring this with a development build, then... stop. Measure with a production build, which precompiles all the templates, instead of compiling them at startup.

Comment: Sweet thanks for that.. I'm for sure doing a development build. It seems though that when I do ng build --prod my index.html file gets deleted for some reason. Is there any fix to that?